# Return block with custom key from multidimensional array

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

From multidimensional array I have to return only this block which have key "widget_section", I've tried with array_key_exists function but it not works. Right now I can return block with specific name. But I can't get block if have array "widget_section" and value is set to 1

```
        $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
        foreach( $blocks as $block ) {
          if( 'acf/home-block-alert' === $block['blockName'] ) {
            echo render_block( $block );
          }
        }
```

My array

```
  [8]=>
  array(5) {
    ["blockName"]=>
    string(20) "acf/home-block-alert"
    ["attrs"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(19) "block_5eecadb49bb7c"
      ["name"]=>
      string(20) "acf/home-block-alert"
      ["data"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["alert_box"]=>
        string(445) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        ["_alert_box"]=>
        string(19) "field_5eecacb7c30b3"
        ["widget_section"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["_widget_section"]=>
        string(19) "field_5ef5be51d1ce2"
      }
      ["mode"]=>
      string(4) "edit"
    }
    ["innerBlocks"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["innerHTML"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["innerContent"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
```

How to deal with it ?

Comment: So...see if this makes sense... you need all the sub-arrays(blocks) that have `widget_section` with value `1`?

Comment: @jibsteroos Hi, thank you for your interest. I have a lot of blocks, but few have sub-array "widget_section" and these blocks which have this sub-array I want to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is verify if `$block['attrs']['data']['widget_section']` `isset()` for each block in your array. If so, store the array, as follows:

```
$store = [];
foreach($blocks as $block) {
    if(isset($block['attrs']['data']['widget_section'])) {
        $store[] = $block;
    }
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/QblFc)

Comment: glad I could help!